# Queries return results in psql shell, but not Django

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm trying to query a GeoIP database with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE api_geoiprecord
(
    start_ip inet PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    end_ip inet NOT NULL,
    region VARCHAR(2),
    country VARCHAR(2),
    city VARCHAR(50),
    postal_code VARCHAR(50),
    latitude DOUBLE PRECISION,
    longitude DOUBLE PRECISION,
    dma_code INT,
    area_code INT
);
```

When I run this query in `psql` I get the result:

```
-- Test address, belongs to Yahoo!
SELECT city, country from api_geoiprecord
WHERE inet '68.180.194.242' BETWEEN start_ip AND end_ip
LIMIT 1;

   city    | country
-----------+---------
 Sunnyvale | CA
(1 row)
```

When I run it in Django I get nothing:

```
def get_location(ip) -> None:
    cur = connection.cursor()
    cur.execute(
        """SELECT city, country FROM api_geoiprecord
           WHERE inet %s BETWEEN start_ip AND end_ip
           LIMIT 1;""",
        (ip, )
    )
    return cur.fetchone()
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Same database? (Same port?) Same role? [Same `search_path`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-to-create-table-inside-specific-schema-by-default-in-postgres/9067777#9067777)

Comment: Same everything, yes.